# JS regex exclude matches inside quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

This code:

```
var value = 'one.two[0]["three.four"]';
console.log(value.split(/(?:\.)|(?=\[")/));
```

produces the following array:

```
0: one
1: two[0]
2: ["three
3: four"]
```

How can I modify it to exclude dots inside quotes?
I'd like to get this output:

```
0: one
1: two[0]
2: ["three.four"]
```

Comment: `\.(?!\w*"\])` .

Comment: It seems you may use [`str.match(/\w+(?:\[[^\][]*])?|\[[^\][]*]/g)`](https://regex101.com/r/gNa9ed/1), or even `\w+(?:\[[^\][]*])?|\[".*?"]|\[[^\][]*]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a negative lookahead after the `.` to add the "exclude dots inside quotes" logic.  We ignore the opening quote and lookahead to see if we're inside a quoted string. (which we're assuming here to not contain any weirdness like escaped  quotes `\"`)

```
var value = 'one.two[0]["three.four.five"]';
console.log(value.split(/\.(?![\w.]*")|(?=\[")/));
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you could try with a combination of:

- negative lookbehind

  `/(?<!not )foo/`
  matches:

  not foo but **foo**
- and negative lookahead

  `/foo(?!bar)/` matches:

  foobar **foo**baz

Regards

Comment: Didn't downvote you but probably because JavaScript lacks support for lookbehinds like `(?<=…)` (positive) and `(?<!…)` (negative)

Comment: probably because it's not an answer.